# Fetching information about hyperlink in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm building a control that is similar to posting a link on facebook. (In javascript) Every time a link is shared, I want to fetch the details just like the way facebook fetches info for that link. For example (look at the link below),  when I typed www.bbc.com, facebook automatically fetched BBC logo, and some summary information and also the images on bbc home page.

[image]

Is there any library that helps me do that in a simple way? I want to build similar control for my own site.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What serverside language are you using? You need that to get the content since JavaScript can not access it.

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial should be what you are looking for: http://www.9lessons.info/2010/06/facebook-like-extracting-url-data-with.html